# iOS - How to make url link clickable in info.plist value

Tags: ios

I have a Info.plist key/value pair contacts permission. I want to have a URL in the value.

What I want is the URL to be clickable/tap when the alert is presented asking for contacts permissions.

How can make it clickable?

Text looks like:

```
This app protects user privacy. Please check www.example.com/Privacy.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. The privacy message is just a string that iOS shows in the privacy alert. Your message should explain (very briefly) why it needs to access to the specific resource.

Don't state that your app protects user privacy. Explain why your app needs to access the user's contacts.

The user already has access to your app's privacy page from your app's description in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

The `dialog` for asking user's `premission` is not able to customize, so you cannot add anything to the `system alert`, you cannot put the link to the `permission` alert.

**EDIT**

you can edit the describe value in the info.plist

Comment: This answer is misleading. The message shown in the alert is provided by the app using the appropriate privacy setting in the Info.plist. So it can be customized to show whatever text the developer wants. It's just that it can only be a simple string.

Comment: @rmaddy i mean developer can not customize the alert. not mean can not edit the describe info in info.plist